# ENOENT (No such file or directory) When There Is A File There

Tags: java, android, png, uri

I am trying to share A PNG with ShareActionProvider in Android. When I open the PNG to the Uri, it says there is no file found.
`open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)` even though I have gone into the file system and have seen it myself. I have tried it on my phone and the AVD with the save error. I have looked around but have found no answers. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is where I try to open the file:

```
 File file = new File(getFilesDir()+"wifiqr/", "QRCode.png");
                file.setReadable(true, false);
                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
                provider.setShareIntent(intent);
```

If it helps here is where I save it:

```
 String fileName = getFilesDir()+"/wifiqr/" + "QRCode.png";
                etSSID.setText(fileName);
                OutputStream stream = null;
                try {
                    stream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
                    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, stream);
                    stream.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Finally the error log:

```
11-15 02:34:43.243      594-892/com.android.mms E/Mms/media: IOException caught while opening or reading stream
        java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.frostbytedev.wifiqr/fileswifiqr/QRCode.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:105)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:447)
        at com.android.mms.model.MediaModel.initMediaSize(MediaModel.java:235)
        at com.android.mms.model.MediaModel.<init>(MediaModel.java:74)
        at com.android.mms.model.RegionMediaModel.<init>(RegionMediaModel.java:36)
        at com.android.mms.model.RegionMediaModel.<init>(RegionMediaModel.java:31)
        at com.android.mms.model.ImageModel.<init>(ImageModel.java:73)
        at com.android.mms.ui.SlideshowEditor.changeImage(SlideshowEditor.java:163)
        at com.android.mms.data.WorkingMessage.internalChangeMedia(WorkingMessage.java:640)
        at com.android.mms.data.WorkingMessage.changeMedia(WorkingMessage.java:588)
        at com.android.mms.data.WorkingMessage.setAttachment(WorkingMessage.java:453)
        at com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity.addImage(ComposeMessageActivity.java:3150)
        at com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity.addAttachment(ComposeMessageActivity.java:3291)
        at com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity.access$5900(ComposeMessageActivity.java:167)
        at com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity$35.run(ComposeMessageActivity.java:3236)
        at com.android.mms.ui.AsyncDialog$ModalDialogAsyncTask.doInBackground(AsyncDialog.java:129)
        at com.android.mms.ui.AsyncDialog$ModalDialogAsyncTask.doInBackground(AsyncDialog.java:84)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
        Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
        ... 24 more
```

Answer (score 2):

The `getFilesDir()` is private to that specific app (i.e., other apps cannot read it) as explained in [openFileOutput](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) (which is the same directory `getFilesDir` returns as per [its documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getFilesDir%28%29)).

If you are attempting to share files across applications, you follow the [Sharing Files training guide](http://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/index.html) to ensure that other applications can access your files.

Answer (score 1):

In your save code you have:

```
String fileName = getFilesDir()+"/wifiqr/" + "QRCode.png";
```

In your load code you have no leading slash before "wifiqr/":

```
File file = new File(getFilesDir()+"wifiqr/", "QRCode.png");
```

It seems you meant to put a "/" before "wifiqr/" in your load code. Your save code implies that `getFilesDir()` may not already have a trailing slash on it.

The name of the file it is trying to open is even printed in your log:

```
/data/data/com.frostbytedev.wifiqr/fileswifiqr/QRCode.png
```

It doesn't seem like you expect to have a directory named "fileswifiqr".

The missing link in your troubleshooting attempt was: While you knew the file you were *intending* to open existed, you still needed to make sure that your code was actually opening the file you were intending to open.

Comment: Fixed that and still get the error and I did look at the path and they have the same exact paths

Comment: And now the error says `/data/data/com.frostbytedev.wifiqr/files/wifiqr/QRCode.png`, and you can verify in other ways that the file exists (e.g. `ls /data/data/com.frostbytedev.wifiqr/files/wifiqr/QRCode.png` in a console shows the file)? And you have printed out the path you are saving to and the path you are loading from and verified that they are the same?

Comment: Yes they are the exact same